# How do I prepend text preserving camelcase

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions

A common process for me is to have a camelCased word that I wish to prepend to. I find the vanilla method a little too cumbersome as I will describe below. What I'm wondering is if there is a better method.

### Example

```
function foo() {
  doSomething();
}
```

In this the `doSomething` is in camel case and I want to turn it into `shouldDoSomething`.

### Things I've tried

Usually I will place the cursor at the beginning of the word and press <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>`should`<kbd>Esc</kbd>. However, this requires positioning the cursor correctly and performing a few operations one of which needs to be undone (<kbd>~</kbd> move cursor to the right requiring an extra <kbd>h</kbd>).

I have also used tpope's [vim-abolish Coercion](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish#coercion) by placing the cursor on the **correct line** and then <kbd>I</kbd>`something_`<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>. Unfortunatly the result of which is `shouldDosomething` not `shouldDoSomething`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `s` to delete the current letter and put you in insert mode.

```
sshouldD<esc>
```

This will let you delete the `s` insert `shouldD` yielding `shouldDoSomething`

Note: assuming you are on the `d`.

Answer (score 1):

how about <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd>
 <kbd>i</kbd> `should` <kbd>Esc</kbd>?

You can save that into a macro and re-use it if you need to do it a lot. Otherwise don't bother optimizing a task you only do once anyway.

EDIT:

If you want to make this a macro you can do `qqbgUli<C-o>q` to save it into the q register. Note that the macro would only be recorded as `qqbgUli`, since `<C-o>q` is what stops the recording without leaving insert mode.

You can also just map it to something like `<C-i>` or `<leader>i` if you use it often. `map <leader>ic bgUli` (`ic` as in **I**nsert preserving **C**amel-case)

Comment: Isn’t that the same thing as `~`? Haven’t really gained much. Though the macro idea is nice.

Comment: Would the `<Ctrl-o>q` cause the second run of the macro to start recording again? Seems like `:let @q = “bgUi”` work better?

Comment: ~ toggles case, which is faster, but gU sets uppercase, which is more accurately what you want. Using `let` should also work, but the <Ctrl-o>q is what stops recording the macro i the first place without leaving insert mode so you can then type the word (assuming it's not always the same, "should")